Want to access the variable value using @input decorator from parent
I want to use a baseurl from parent which can be used for further process in child
Dashboard is Parent
  `<div class="layout-wrapper" [ngClass]="containerClass">
  <app-topbar></app-topbar>
   <div class="layout-main-container">
   <div class="layout-main">
     <router-outlet baseurl='MY_API_URL'></router-outlet>
    </div>
     <app-footer></app-footer>
   </div>
  <app-config></app-config>
  </div>`

I want a setup thus if in future i need to change  the baseurl i can change it from the the  tag only
for that the code for the respective child would be like
       export class SpecimenComponent implements OnInit { @Input() baseurl = '';

In the parent component where you want all the children to have the same base url, create a service, ensure it does not have providedIn: 'root' and add it to the parent component like so
@Component({
    providers: [UrlService],
})
export class ParentComponent {
    const urlService = inject(UrlService);

    ngOnInit() {
        this.urlService.baseUrl = 'http://example.com';
    }
}

Then importing the service, ensures all the child URLs have the same URL to be shared, it's not possible to use @Input or @Output for routes, from my knowledge.
Using the service in the providers array, we ensure the service has a new instance created, so only the parent and its children, have access to the URL you set.
